# Best way to determine if a user has viewed data

Tags: database-design

What is the best method to determine if a user has viewed a piece of data, ie like an update to a comment. The two solutions I have thought about are these....

1. Use a separate table that has a row for each user and the data id that is being viewed and inserting into when the item was last viewed.
2. Use the same table and add a row for every user when the item is changed and delete that row when the user actually views the data.

Both methods solve the problem but in solution 2 the maximum rows for the table would at worst equal that of solution 1, no one viewed anything, and at best has 0 rows, everything has been viewed. I know in solution 2 you have no way to determine when it was viewed.

Thoughts?

Edit: I was using an update to a comment as an example. In the actual application, new users wouldn't be expected to view or read old data. It would mean nothing to them for they just joined.

Answer (score 3):

It's got to be option 1:

**Table 1 (comment)**

- comment_id
- comment

**Table 2 (comment_view)**

- comment_id
- user_id

Option 2 will not work because every **new** user will have every existing comment "marked read."

Answer (score 3):

do you need to know when or how many times they viewed a piece of data?

If not I'd keep a table with a FK to the data-updated and a FK to the user. then a simple check to see if they viewed:

```
select count(*) from DataAlerts where dataid = 1 and userid = 1
```

when data is updated insert records for the data and users.

when a user views delete that user.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 is the better approach here - generally, deleting something to indicate that something has happened is a strange way to do things in a database, and as ng.mangine indicated above, it won't even work (unless you add rows to that table every time there's a new user, but THAT is almost certain to be a bottleneck and perf issue - consider what happens when you have a million comments and a new user joins).

Option 1 is much clearer; only think about changing it if you encounter performance issues (or if you happen to know in advance that your traffic will require a more optimized strategy, like bit vectors on each topic representing read / unread for each system user).

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 is an *unusual* way of doing things, which in the database world is a way of saying it *might* work but it's probably best to go with a more traditional approach like Option 1.